# How to show random characters on button with tableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-tablelayout

I have created 18 buttons in TableLayout with 3 rows every tablerow  contain 
   6 buttons, but what i wanted is to set the text of these button to random 
   chars so  i made an array of all chars so  rondomly each button will get 
   a random char. the random array works pretty fine but when i launch the app 
   the layout got messed and all i can see is this

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.game.knight.tablerow.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="404dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn10"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn11"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn12"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn13"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn14"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn15"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn16"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn17"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn18"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

================================================================

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] alphabets = {

                "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
                "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
                "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
        };



            TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);


            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    String str = alphabets[r.nextInt(alphabets.length)];
                    btnTag.setText(str);

                }

                layout.addView(row);

            }
            setContentView(layout);

        }
```

I want to show something like this:

[image]

(i design it) i mean how can i keep this design in the same time get the random chars?

Comment: [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array) explains how to shuffle an array using Collections.

Comment: Have you considered using a GridView instead?

Comment: @Barns52  gridview looks more complecated i want to work with buttons looks nice